# Sequence contains no elements in asp core and sql server 2016

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, dapper

I need to return info from database with `T-SQL` and I'm using dapper.

I've written this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserActivetionCode UA 
WHERE UA.Username=@Username 
AND UA.ActivetionCode= @ActivetionCode 
AND UA.ExpireTime > GETDATE()
```

and I'm using this code:

```
var find = await roleConnection.QueryFirstAsync(command, new { 
    @ActivetionCode = ActivetionCode, 
    @Username = Username });
```

but it shows me this error:

> Sequence contains no elements

Comment: This message says, there is no record returned. You need to check whether you have any record where expiretime is greater than current datetime. GetDate() return current date time value. This means, expiretime must have a future value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the query didn't return any results.
If you don't want to get it, use `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync`.
This will result with `default(T)` (`T` being whatever datatype the query should return) if the query returned no rows.

However, `QueryFirst` implies a known order in the resultset, which your query does not provide (as it doesn't have an `order by` clause) and in any case, I suspect that the combination of `Username` and `ActivetionCode` should probably be unique. In that case, I would go with `QuerySingleOrDefault`, which will throw an exception if the query returned more than one result.